# oci_execute(): ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: php, sql, oracle, data-binding

I don't understand what the error is telling me. I'm not inserting any LONG data so why am I getting the error `oci_execute(): ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column`?

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (id, fname, lname, position, email, created_date, created_by, updated_date, updated_by)
    VALUES (contacts_seq.NEXTVAL, :firstname, :lastname, :position, :email, sysdate, :user_id, NULL, NULL)";

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":firstname", $firstname);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":lastname", $lastname);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":position", $position);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":email", $email);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":user_id", $user_id);

while(($data = fgetcsv($resource)) !== false) {
    if($row === 1) {
        # Skip the first row since they are only headers.
        $row++;
        continue;
    } else {
        $firstname = str_replace("\n", " ", trim($data[0]));
        $lastname = str_replace("\n", " ", trim($data[1]));
        $position = str_replace("\n", " ", trim($data[2]));
        $email = str_replace("\n", " ", trim($data[3]));

        oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT);
    }
}

oci_commit($objConn);
oci_free_statement($stmt);
```

It doesn't make sense to me because all the variables I'm binding are `strings`.

#### Additional Info

The only `LONG` column is the `id` since it's an `INTEGER`. The other columns are all `VARCHAR2` and `DATE`.

Comment: 'Long' in this context is Oracle `LONG` data type, which is a long string - the precursor to CLOBs. Not the C numeric `long` type. Does one of your C strings exceed 4000 characters? (Or 2000, depending on the character set). What are the data types of the table columns?

Comment: @AlexPoole I don't know why you're asking about `Java` strings but all the strings I'm binding could have "around" 500 characters.

Comment: Yeah, neither do I, code-blindness... the length of one of them is going to be causing this error though, can you check the length of the actual values when the exception is thrown? Maybe the limit is lower than I thought - what is your DB character set, and do you have multibyte characters in the strings?

Comment: @AlexPoole the datatypes of the colums are `INTEGER` for the `id`, `VARCHAR2` for the columns I'm binding the variables to, and `DATE` for the others.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've checked the values being bound and according to the `var_dump`, here's what they are like: `string(6): "Thomas"`. I have 2 CSV files. I'm currently working on the easier one which only has around 50 characters for each field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109830/discussion-between-patrick-gregorio-and-alex-poole).